# How to get querystring value to Kendo Grid update method and pass to MVC controller

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid and need to get a querystring value.  See below code.

Browser Url = http://blahblah/blah/36?EvaluationCriteriaGrid-mode=edit&chiefEvalCriteriaId=110

UI.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ChiefEvaluationCriteriaList.AsEnumerable())
                        .Name("EvaluationCriteriaGrid")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {

                            columns.Bound(p => p.EvaluationCriteriaName);
                            columns.Bound(p => p.MinScore).Width(100).Title("Min Score").Format("{0:0}");
                            columns.Bound(p => p.MaxScoreDisplay).Width(100).Title("Max Score");
                            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(180).Title("Action");
                        })
                        .CellAction(cell =>
                        {
                            if (cell.Column.Title == "Action")
                            {
                                if (cell.DataItem.EvaluationResultID ==
                                    ServiceProxy.Model.DomainConstants.EVALUATION_RESULT_APPROVED)
                                {
                                    cell.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "display:none;";
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                        .Pageable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .Scrollable()
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Server()
                        .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.ChiefEvaluationCriteriaID))
                        .Read("EvaluationQuestionnaire", "EvaluationCriteria", new { area = "Proposal", Id = Model.SolicitationDetails.SolicitationID })
                        .Update("EditEvaluationCriteria", "EvaluationCriteria", new { area = "Proposal", Id = Model.SolicitationDetails.SolicitationID })

                    )

                )
```

Controller.cs

```
[HttpPost]

 public ActionResult EditEvaluationCriteria( int Id, int chiefEvalCriteriaId, int maxScoreDisplay, int minScoreDisplay = 0 )
        {

               if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                       Do something
                     }
 

                    return view

        }
```

Thank you for the support

Comment: What is your problem? The parameters in the action method are being filled ?

Comment: When you click "Edit" and enter values, then click "Update" the controller get all the values in the ActionResult except the "chiefEvalCriteriaId" which is in the query string.

Comment: Try `Request.QueryString["chiefEvalCriteriaId"]`.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - Your suggestion resulted to a solution for my problem.  I added an additional property to the Anonymous type within the Update method of the Kendo grid.  See code here >>> .Update("EditEvaluationCriteria", "EvaluationCriteria", new { area = "Proposal", Id = Model.SolicitationDetails.SolicitationID, chiefEvalCriteriaId = Request.QueryString["ChiefEvaluationCriteriaID"] })  Thank you for your support.

Comment: Nice.. youre welcome.